# Double summation involving factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the value of $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{m\cdot n}{(m+n)!}$.

My try: $$\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\bigg(\frac{m}{(m+1)! }+\frac{2m}{(m+2)!}+\cdots\cdots +\frac{m+\infty}{(m+\infty)!}\bigg)$$

I did not understand how to start it.

I could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: Fix $m$ and then figure out what happens to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m\cdot n}{(m+n)!}$, it should be a function $m$. Then you can sum this function with the outer sum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that by letting $k=m+n$, we have that (terms can be arranged because they are non-negative),
$$\begin{align}
\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{m\cdot n}{(m+n)!}
&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n(k-n)=
\frac{1}{6}\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{k^3-k}{k!}\\&=\frac{1}{6}\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)+3k(k-1)}{k!}\\
&=
\frac{1}{6}\sum^{\infty}_{k=3}\frac{1}{(k-3)!}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\frac{1}{(k-2)!}\\
&=\frac{e}{6}+\frac{e}{2}=\frac{2e}{3}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Dear Robert, I did not understand how you did the change of variable for the indexes, and how you substitue $k$  instead of $m$, can you explain it please?

Comment: @Nizar Consider $\mathbb{N}^+\times\mathbb{N}^+$ as the union of the diagonals $\{(1,1)\}\cup\{(2,1),(1,2)\}\cup\{(3,1),(2,2),(1,3)\}\cup\dots$.

Comment: @Nizar It's the change of indices from $(m;n)$ to $(k;n)$ where $k=m+n$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that it is valid to rearrange the terms of the series because its terms are non-negative (by Tonelli's theorem).

Comment: @Maxim Of course... thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @RobertZ Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

The slickest approaches have already been outlined by Marco and Robert, so I will show an overkill just for fun. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\frac{1}{n!}=[z^n]e^z = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{e^z}{z^{n+1}}\,dz $, hence

$$ \sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{mn}{(m+n)!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{m}{z^m}\cdot\frac{n}{z^n}\cdot\frac{e^z}{z}\,dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{z e^{z}}{(1-z)^4}\,dz $$
and
$$ \sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{mn}{(m+n)!}=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=1}\frac{z e^z}{(1-z)^4} =\color{red}{\frac{2e}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\sum_{m\geq1}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{mn}{\left(n+m\right)!}=\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(m-1\right)!}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n}{\left(n-1\right)!}\int_{0}^{1}t^{m}\left(1-t\right)^{n-1}dt$$ $$=e\int_{0}^{1}t\left(2-t\right)dt=\color{red}{\frac{2}{3}e}$$ where the exchange of the series and the integral is justified by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Using generating functions: let's start off with
$$F(x, y) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^m y^n} {(m+n)!}.$$
If we group the terms with $m+n = k$, we get $\frac{1}{k!} (x^k + x^{k-1} y + \cdots + y^k) = \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{x^{k+1} - y^{k+1}}{x-y}$.  Therefore,
$$F(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{x^{k+1} - y^{k+1}}{x-y} = \frac{x e^x - y e^y}{x-y}.$$
Now,
$$F_{xy}(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{mn}{(m+n)!} x^{m-1} y^{n-1}.$$
Thus, the original sum is equal to $F_{xy}(1, 1)$.  From here, it would be a straightforward but tedious calculation to find a closed-form formula for $F_{xy}$.  That will give a fraction with $(x-y)^3$ in the denominator; however, it is not hard to see that $F_{xy}$ should be continuous at $(1,1)$, so you can calculate the value at $(1,1)$ as a limit of this quotient as $(x,y) \to (1,1)$.  (For example, first substituting $x=1$ since $\{ (1,y) \mid y \ne 1 \}$ has cluster point at $(1,1)$, and then either using l'Hopital's rule three times or expanding a Taylor series about $y=1$ should work.)  This will give the final answer $\frac{2}{3} e$.

For instance, in a Maxima session, I get (with a little hand editing of the transcript):

```
(%i1) diff(diff((x*exp(x)-y*exp(y))/(x-y),x),y);

(%i2) limit(limit(%o1,x,1),y,1);
          2 %e
(%o2)     ----
           3
```

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{mn \over \pars{m + n}!} & =
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{mn \over
\pars{m - 1}!\, n!}\,{\Gamma\pars{m}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{m + n + 1}!}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{m \over \pars{m - 1}!\pars{n - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{m - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] &=
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{m\, t^{m - 1} \over \pars{m - 1}!}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{1 - t}^{n} \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\underbrace{\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{m + 1}t^{m} \over m!}}_{\ds{=\ \expo{t}\pars{1 + t}}}\
\underbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{1 - t}^{n + 1} \over n!}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{=\ \expo{1 -t}\pars{1 - t}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t = \bbx{{2 \over 3}\,\expo{}}
\approx 1.8122
\end{align}